# Setting form select values before adding them to the DOM with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select

Is it possible to select the option of a select input element in an HTML form with JQuery BEFORE adding the element to the DOM?

Comment: Do you have some code to share? Set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here is a fiddle I set up to show how you could do this AFTER the DOM has loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/Sp6tK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
You can construct any html and manipulate it before inserting it into the DOM.

```
var $select = $("<select>");
$("<option value='val1'>Value1</option>").appendTo($select);
$("<option value='val2' selected>Value2</option>").appendTo($select);
$select.appendTo($("#someElement"));    // (add element to DOM)
```